# iN wordpress...I want dont want to allow user to see any page without login

Tags: php, wordpress

iN wordpress.I want dont want to allow user to see any page without login. at the moment that can see home page.but I want to redirect them to login page without login.they cannt access any page of the website without login.any one has an idea how to do this in wordpress??

Comment: I think you are looking for [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/).

Answer (score 4):

header.php is included in each page, 
you can check with this **get_current_user_id();** this function returns 0 if not any user in logged in.

in header.php

```
<?php 

if( !get_current_user_id()  && !preg_match('/login/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){  // checks if the user is not logged in and the page is not login page,
 // redirect to some other page,
 header("Location: ". site_url().'/wp-login/' ); // redirecting to login page
 exit()


}
?>
```

Comment: when I add this code...it gives an error as below.   The webpage at http://localhost/photogallery/?page_id=24 has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer. @Abuzer Firdousi

Comment: ops, yes it will cause redirects, 
need to add 1 more condition in if, if the page is not login page,

what is the url of your login page?  http://site.com/wp-login/ or some else.

Comment: if(!strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?page_id=24')) {
   header("Location:".home_url()."/?page_id=24"); // redirecting to login page
   exit();

Comment: I have put that condition.My problem is solved thnxxxxx so much @ Abuzer Firdousi

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a function to check for whether a user is logged in called [is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in).

So the logic to place at the top of the header.php would be:

```
<?php
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
  header("Location: http://www.LoginPageUrl.com/");
}
?>
```

Comment: thnx for the help. @#rogMaHall